# Variation of Steinhaus Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof of the problem,

For $A$ and $B$ measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite measure, show that $A+B$ contains an interval of positive length,

it says that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_A\ast\chi_B(x)d\mu (x)=\mu(A)\mu(B)$$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $$\chi_A\ast\chi_B(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_A(x-t)\chi_B(t)d\mu(t)=\mu((x-A)\cap B).$$
How is it shown to be true?

Comment: By finite measure do you mean positive measure?

Comment: @Vim In this problem, yes.